# Mysql said: #1422 - Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger

Tags: mysql

In the code below I'm trying to create a trigger which inserts 'incidentimg' table id along with an image path if the user of the web application did not upload a image with the form belonging to 'incidentreport' table, however, I'm only getting the error "*MySQL said: #1422 - Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger*"

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `insertImage`;
CREATE TRIGGER `insertImage` AFTER INSERT ON `incidentreport` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    IF(SELECT incidentimg.incidentImgId FROM incidentimg 
       LEFT JOIN incidentreport ON incidentimg.imgs_incidentReportId = incidentreport.incidentReportId 
       WHERE incidentimg.incidentImgId IS NULL) 
       THEN INSERT INTO incidentimg(incidentImgId, imgUrl)values(NEW.incidentReportId, 'images/no-image.png'); 
    END IF; 
END
;
```

Here are the tables being used
[image]

Can someone assist me on how to correct this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got the code to work. Now the code will check whether 'incidentimg' table has all the 'incidentReportId' that the 'incidentreport' table has, and if it doesn't then the last inserted id from the 'incidentreport' table along with a default image path will be inserted into 'incidentimg' table AFTER INSERT.

```
CREATE TRIGGER insertImage AFTER INSERT ON incidentreport
FOR EACH ROW    
BEGIN
    IF(SELECT incidentreport.incidentReportId 
        FROM incidentreport
        LEFT JOIN incidentimg ON incidentreport.incidentReportId = incidentimg.imgs_incidentReportId
        WHERE incidentimg.imgs_incidentReportId IS NULL)
        THEN INSERT INTO incidentimg(imgs_incidentReportId, imgUrl) VALUES(NEW.incidentReportId, 'images/no-image.png');
    END IF;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not much sure but I am guessing that probably it's because of the `IF .. THEN` conditional `INSERT`. Try modifying your `INSERT` statement with an `EXISTS` like

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `insertImage`;
CREATE TRIGGER `insertImage` AFTER INSERT ON `incidentreport` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO incidentimg(incidentImgId, imgUrl)
SELECT NEW.incidentReportId, 'images/no-image.png'
FROM DUAL WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT 1 FROM incidentimg 
       LEFT JOIN incidentreport 
ON incidentimg.imgs_incidentReportId = incidentreport.incidentReportId 
WHERE incidentimg.incidentImgId IS NULL
)  
END;
```

Comment: Are you still getting the same error? I believe it's that SELECT statement; can you explain what's you are trying to do with that SELECT statement?

Comment: In the web app, the user is supposed to complete a step wizard, where the first part of the form belongs to the 'incidentreport' report and the next section for uploading images (incidentimg table), but a user doesn't have to upload image(s). Therefore, with the select statement I'm trying to check whether any data was inserted into the 'incidentimg' table after 'incidentreport' table is populated by checking if that that entry is null... Hope this is clear @Rahul